# Relation of the normalizers of maximal tori in reductive Lie groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected reductive Lie group over $\mathbb{C}$, $K$ a maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and $T$ a  maximal torus of $K$.

Question: For the normalizers of $T$, is it true that the normalizer $N_G(T)=N_K(T)C_G(T)$? Any "elementary" proof?

Here $C_G(T)$ denotes the centralizer of $T$ in $G$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what you mean by "reductive Lie group", or else to use a more common name lkke "semisimple".   The term "reductive" comes from the theory of linear algebraic groups; it suggests complete reducibility of finite dimensional representations, which is only true in characteristic 0, etc.

Comment: @JimHumphreys. I think the term "reductive" is quite clear also in the context of Lie groups. I take it to mean that the Lie algebra is a product of a semisimple and an abelian one. If there are problems with the concept, let me know.

Comment: @Sebastian: I think the ambiguity comes into the proviso that the Lie algebra involves an abelian part.    Does the additive Lie group qualify as "reductive", or the product of this group with a simple Lie group?  This is pretty far from the Borel-Tits notion of reductive algebraic group.

Comment: @JimHumphreys I see your point. But for the purpose of this question, I think we may assume that noncompact abelian groups are allowed as factors of $G$, and see if we can still get an answer. For motivation, in the category of Lie groups one can (maybe should) always ask which results extend to the universal covering.

Comment: @Sebastian:  "Abelian Lie group" is too broad here.    Even Wallach's book *Real Reductive Groups I* gives an algebraic defini.tion of "real reductive Lie group". The problem is that a vector group is not a reductive Lie group (say over $\mathbb{C}$).